# Radio button values doesnt go to database

Tags: asp.net, forms, asp.net-core, authentication, view

Hello  I code a form login page in asp.net core and I made a controller to send the data to database but unfortunately It doesnt go to database:

```
IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection();
dbConnection.ConnectionString = "SERVER=PEDRAM;Database=Resume1;User Id=sa;Password=1;";
dbConnection.Open();
DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();

switch (model.Gender)
{
    case "male":
        parameters.Add("@Gender", "1");
        break;
    case "female":
        parameters.Add("@Gender", "0");
        break;
    default:
        parameters.Add("@Gender", null);
        break;
}


CREATE  TABLE [Identity].[User]
(
    UserId int Not Null Constraint Pk_Identity_User_UserId  Primary Key,
    Gender BIT,
    ModifiedDate DateTime Not Null  Default(GetDate())
)
GO
CREATE  PROC   [Identity].Usp_Ins_User
    @Gender BIT
As
    Begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    Begin Try
    Begin Tran Identity_Ins_User
      Insert INTO [Identity].[User] (Gender)
      Values (@Gender)
      SELECT 1
      Commit Tran Identity_Ins_User
    End Try
Begin Catch
    Rollback  Tran Identity_Ins_User
    SELECT 0
End   Catch
End
GO
```

Comment: Did you execute  anything? Please show the whole code where you use the connection to execute a command using those parameters

Comment: Still I can't see anything here that executes anything. Data doesn't go to the database if you don't execute a command.

Comment: But I executed All the codes in Sql server And Asp.net

Comment: I think you need to add more details on your issue. My suggestions is you can check if your http request contains correct information by using f12 in the browser, and you can add break point in your controller to check if the controller received correct data, and so on to locate the error line-code.